# How do I get text inside the xml tag

Tags: xml, parsing, tags

I got a xml document that looks like this:

```
<recenttracks user="xxxxxx" page="1" perPage="200" totalPages="2" total="233">
<track>
<artist mbid="160629ab-ec18-4931-8c95-02cb92d06186">Foreigner</artist>
<name>Long, Long Way From Home</name>
<streamable>1</streamable>
<mbid>1be3ee4b-98e7-4690-b872-ccabbccd09af</mbid>
<album mbid="4e1cf1f8-2383-434d-9125-6c28028db9d0">No End In Sight</album>
</track>
```

Now I need to get to the totalPages property inside  now I know how to get the information between two tags for instance the name tag like this: $track->name but got no clue how to get the information inside a tag anyone?

Comment: Parse the XML and fetch the information out of the resulting structure. Since you're not even disclosing which language/platform you want to do this with, no more detailed answer is possible.

Comment: oh I i so sorry forgot to mention, i am using php simple xml. right now the code looks like this and I get the artists from the xml: http://pastebin.com/2ibFvBf3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), to get attribute value, use following syntax:

```
$recenttracks['totalPages'];
```

PS: I don't know anything about PHP Simple XML, I just heard about google, so I might be wrong.

Comment: $recenttracks = $xml->recenttracks; echo $recenttracks['totalPages']; works great, thanks